# Bash: nested loop one way comparison

Tags: bash, loops, nested, triangular, oneway

I have one queston about nested loop with bash.

I have an input files with one file name per line (full path)
I read this file and then i make a nest loop:

```
    for i in $filelines ; do
    echo $i
    for j in $filelines ; do
         ./program $i $j
    done
done
```

The program I within the loop is pretty low.
Basically it compare the file A with the file B.

I want to skip A vs A comparison (i.e comparing one file with itslef) AND
I want to avoid permutation (i.e. for file A and B, only perform A against B and not B against A).

What is the simplest to perform this?

Comment: Compare the filenames and run `./program` if they are different.  Use an `if` statement to compare the values of `$i` and `$j`.

Comment: tje program is a camparison on what is in theses files

Comment: Yes but what I propose is to compare the filenames.  `$i` and `$j` values are the filenames.  So if you do an if to compare them, you will know if it is the same file.

Comment: Ok I removed my answer, I did not read properly and you want permutations as well.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2: this one takes care of permutations

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpunsorted="/tmp/compare_unsorted"
tmpsorted="/tmp/compare_sorted"

>$tmpunsorted

while read linei
do
    while read linej
    do
        if [ $linei != $linej ]
        then
            echo $linei $linej | tr " " "\n" | sort | tr "\n" " " >>$tmpunsorted
            echo >>$tmpunsorted
        fi
    done <filelines
done <filelines

sort $tmpunsorted | uniq > $tmpsorted

while read linecompare
do
    echo "./program $linecompare"
done <$tmpsorted

# Cleanup
rm -f $tmpunsorted
rm -f $tmpsorted
```

What is done here:

- I use the while loop to read each line, twice, i and j
- if the value of the lines is the same, forget them, no use to consider them
- if they are different, output them into a file ($tmpunsorted).  And they are sorted in alphebetical order before going tothe $tmpunsorted file.  This way the arguments are always in the same order.  So `a b` and `b a` will be same in the unsorted file.
- I then apply `sort | uniq` on $tmpunsorted, so the result is a list of individual argument pairs.
- finally loop on the $tmpsorted file, and call the program on each individual pair.
- Since I do not have your program, I did an echo, which you should remove to use the script.

Comment: Yeah
I think about it but it only solve the easy case A vs A                                              I want to avoid duplicate comparison A vs B and B vs A too

Comment: Nice! I have sligthly change the code to fit my needs. It works well.